# Updating pointers within Mongoose Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi so I am working on a project using MongoDB and Mongoose.

I have a scheme where I check if a certain attribute exists for a given Mongoose object; if it doesn't I create a new one with a pointer; if there exists one I merely get a pointer to it.

Now I update the contents of these pointers, and I attempt to .save() the Mongoose object. However it does not update. I've used console logs and it tells me that the pointers have changed but not the actual contents inside the Mongoose objects. Has anyone else come by this problem? Is there any way around this? Does it matter the order I do it (as in if I push data into an attribute of the object then I modify the contents of the pointer or visa-versa)?

I also thought about how pointers get affected by pushing into arrays, but if I remember correctly java shallow copies content into arrays. So the pointers should still point to the same object?

Thanks

```
Model.findOne({ name: personA.name }, function(err, model) {
   // if such an object exists dbModel points to it otherwise create new object
   var dbModel;
   if(model) dbModel = model;
   else dbModel = new Model({
      name: personA.name,
      hobbies: []
   });
   var newHobby;
   // helper function returns index of object in the array with sports = basketball
   // if no such object exists returns -1
   hobbyIdx = indexOfWithAttr(dbModel.hobbies, "sports", "basketball");
   if(hobbyIdx == -1) {
       newHobby = {
          sports: basketball,
          gears: [] 
       }
       dbModel.hobbies.push(newHobby);
    }
    else { newHobby = dbModels.hobbies[hobbyIdx]; }
    // code changing contents of newHobby goes here...
    newHobby.gears.push("sneakers");

    // then finally save...
    dbModel.save();
}
```

then the output is

```
//prints '{ sports: basketball }'
console.log(newHobby);

// prints '{ name: John, hobbies: [{ sports: basketball }] }'
console.log(dbModel);
```